# Firebase Realtime Database data change

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I've never faced this type of weird problem. When I wanted to update the data of two, it worked fine but when I wanted to update for total, it changes to my desired value first and then automatically turns into 1 again and a notification of my app is shown. See the video attached below for better understanding.

https://streamable.com/akhzjk

[automatically turns into 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiRMm.png)

I didn't understand. Can it be because of my code?
My Project's Reatime database structure
[realtime database structure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrtzP.png)
[realtime database structure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvdQP.png)
Here's my source code

```java
reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(uuid).child("product");
        giverating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        Product product = new Product();
                        int rate=0,total;
                        total=product.getTotal();
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String newid=postSnapshot.getValue(Product.class).getId();
                            if (newid.equals(uid)){
//                                total= product.getTotal();
                                if(finalrate==5){
                                    rate=product.getFive();
                                    stringrate="five";
                                }
                                else if(finalrate==4){
                                    rate=product.getFour();
                                    stringrate="four";
                                }
                                else if(finalrate==3){
                                    rate=product.getThree();
                                    stringrate="three";
                                }
                                else if(finalrate==2){
                                    rate=product.getTwo();
                                    stringrate="two";
                                }
                                else if(finalrate==1){
                                    rate=product.getOne();
                                    stringrate="one";
                                }
                                rate += 1;
                                total+=1;
                                reference.child(uid).child(stringrate).setValue(rate);
                                reference.child(uid).child("total").setValue(total);
                                Toast.makeText(ProductDetails.this,"Your rating has been taken",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Here's my product class

```java
public class Product {
    private String id,title,price,days,uid;
    int five,four,three,two,one,total;
    private String image;
    public Product(){

    }

    public Product(String id, String image, String title, String price, String days,String uid,int five,int four,int three,int two,int one,int total) {
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.days = days;
        this.uid=uid;
        this.five=five;
        this.four=four;
        this.three=three;
        this.two=two;
        this.one=one;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public int getFive(){return five;}


    public int getFour() {
        return four;
    }

    public int getThree() {
        return three;
    }

    public int getTwo() {
        return two;
    }

    public int getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setDays(String days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public void setFive(int five) {
        this.five = five;
    }

    public void setFour(int four) {
        this.four = four;
    }

    public void setThree(int three) {
        this.three = three;
    }

    public void setTwo(int two) {
        this.two = two;
    }

    public void setOne(int one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your document not triggering any cloud functions?

Comment: my code is updating it I guess but I have no clue how is that possible? I'm just retrieving value, it should not update it to 1. @GabrielNexT

Comment: Post your code, maybe it's doing some operation on onSnapshotChange.

Comment: Posted it @GabrielNexT

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: I commented all lines that contains total variable and the problem is gone but I need the variable @AlexMamo

Comment: I don't have any errors. @AlexMamo

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Is the data written in the database?